# How to publish binaries TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, build-definition

Whenever i do the publish its having the CS and Solution files as well.

I tried too many things but all in vain
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeEo1.jpg)

These are my MS build arguments
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying a package location in your MSBuild arguments: `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\CC`. That's the path you want to publish as an artifact if all you want is the packaged binaries.

The path you're currently specifying, `$(agent.builddirectory)\s\Main\State` is the location used by the build agent to synchronize source code, so *of course* you're capturing source code when you publish that as an artifact.

Comment: So what i need to specify to get the packaged binaries only

Comment: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\CC if i use this as path to publish it create a zip file and when i extract that after too many folder structure i get to see the published files. WHat is they way to directly create binaries in a single folder and without Zip.

Thanks for the help.. Much appreciated..

Comment: Can you please help